# Não está pegando o Id do Usuário correto core.net

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando ASP.NET CORE 2.0, e estou precisando pegar o Id do usuário logado.  Este é meu Account Controller:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }


}
```

Estou tentando pegar o id desta forma:

```
 ApplicationUser a = new ApplicationUser();
            CR.FuncionarioId =  a.Id;
```

Porém, este é o id que está no banco:

> 5e7d4078-6388-43e5-8dac-4378f5b366bc

Porém ele está me retornando um id completamente diferente, porque isto está ocorrendo? Utilizo Identity.
Ai quando utilizo o a.Id, cada hora que eu logo, mesmo sendo com o mesmo usuário, ele trás um Id diferente, e não está trazendo o Id que está cadastrado na tabela AspnetUsers.

Comment: Acontece porque a cada hora você da um new ApplicationUser(), é óbvio que a cada chamada vai criar um ID novo, você tem que carregar o ID do usuário logado, não criar um toda hora.

Comment: E como eu faço isso ?

Comment: `var user = await _signInManager.GetUserAsync(User);` e depois `CR.FuncionarioId =  user.Id;`